# What do people with red flags signify?

Tags: triathlon

Watching the Montreal triathlon there's something bugging me

[image]

What do people with red flags signify? They seem to be part of the organisation since they are peppered throughout the course and being from Montreal, I don't remember any recent cause that could manifest itself through a red flag.

So what do they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [briefing document](https://www.triathlon.org/uploads/docs/BRIEFING_2016_Gold_Coast-briefing-elite.pdf) for the elite athletes says that red flags are cautions.